# How to write a Python Selenium script that can check a website for new information?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im new to programming and as a first project I wanted to write a script in Python with Selenium that can check my schools website and give me a notification when I receive a new grade. I already wrote a code in Python with Selenium that logs in to my account and goes to my grades. But what I don't know is how to let it constantly check for new grades and that when there is a new one, it sends me a notification to my iPhone via SMS, Whatsapp, email or another way. I really hope that someone has time to answer my question! Thanks a lot!

Here is the code I wrote so far (I replaced sensitive information with ******* so that you can't see it ;)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

PATH = "/Users/***********/Documents/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://minkema.magister.net/magister/#/cijfers")

search = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
search.send_keys("******")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

try:
    password_login = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "rswp_password"))
    )
except:
    driver.quit()

password_inloggen = driver.find_element_by_id("rswp_password")
password_inloggen.send_keys("*********")
password_inloggen.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: you would need to explore the scheduler which can run the script periodically like cron job or scheduling through jenkin type of pipeline tools.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need to use some scheduler like a cronjob to check the site periodically
then you'll have to use a database to store the grades that are already sent to you so it won't be sent every time the script runs.
and as a notification tool, I would recommend using a Telegram bot.